# How do layout how items are shown in asp gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to change the way gridview shows its items according to the format below.

---

```
  <img1>          <img2>           <img3>          <img4>
<caption1>      <caption1>        <caption1>     <caption1>

  <img5>          <img6>           <img7>          <img8>
<caption5>      <caption6>        <caption7>     <caption8>
```

and so on...

---

Comment: Please define what data you get in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom formatting options with the **DataList or Repeater controls** instead of a GridView. Check these examples for help :

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/aspnet-creating-shopping-cart-example.html.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/formatting-the-datalist-and-repeater-based-upon-data-vb

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoGenerateColumn` property of gridview to false and then use   `<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>` under `<Columns>` section to add controls the way you like.

Comment: Thanks legendnmaking, I was looking for <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>.

I want to do something like how amazon displays "results" http://www.amazon.com/Power-Packs-Automotive/b/ref=amb_link_83808091_1?ie=UTF8&node=1253955011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-5&pf_rd_r=1CT7HP62GZ38K2FV87H6&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1421833882&pf_rd_i=507846

Comment: Repeater control is good to go when you need highly customized output.. it will produce eye-candy output but takes more development time ..